# change the extension ".xlsm" to ".pdf" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I Wanna change the extension of my Excel file in pdf using VBA without actually changing the file into pdf.
Like if you change yourself the extension when u rename the file on your folder.

Sorry my english isn't that good :)

I Made this code so far :

```
Sub Create_pdf()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Nom = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).FullName
Nom = Left(Nom, Len(Nom) - 5) & "_" & Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date)
Call Deverouiller_Classeur
Call Deverouiller_Feuille

Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(Nom & ".pdf")
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Call Verouiller_Classeur

MsgBox ("Le fichier au format .pdf a été enregisté sous : " & Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Path)


End Sub
```

The file is correctly create with the extension PDF but is unreadable.
thanks for your help

The problem is that the file should be upload in an online app but the extension ".xlsm" can't be uplaod so we found a loophole by changing the extension to pdf, upload that file ".pdf" on the app, after what we download and change back the extension to ".xlsm"

Comment: Why don't you save the workbook with the regular extension and rename it (of course after closing it). Use the `name` command in VBA - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: Because it's a file that will be use by other people and they have to transfer the file by the online app only and we don't wanna tell them that they have to change the extension in .pdf to bypass our own security if see what I mean. 
The name command delete the source file and that's not what we need. 
We need to keep the ".xlsm" file and add in the same folder the ".pdf" file

Comment: I understand your attempts to bypass security. But I don't understand your comment. Just remove the `& ".pdf"` when you store the file. Then close it (you do already) and issue a `name` command to rename it. No other people involved. Note that you are currenly creating and saving a blank Excel using the default format, which is probably `xlsx`, not `xlsm`.